# struts.action.extension to "jsp" not working

Tags: java, struts2

I am doing my struts2 application so i was try to include Struts constant **struts.action.extension** into **jsp** extension but its shows page not found error.Here is code what i tried,

struts.xml :

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
   <struts>
   <!-- <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"></constant>-->
   <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="jsp"/>  
   <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default"  >
   <action name="LoginClass" class="com.struts2.LoginCheckingClass" method="execute">
   <result name="success">/LoginSuccessPage.jsp</result>
   <result name="input">/Home.jsp</result> 
   </action>   
   </package>  
   </struts>
```

Home.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="LoginClass" method="post">

<s:textfield name="Uname" label="User Name" />

<s:textfield name="Pwd" label="Password" />

<s:submit Value="Login" />

</s:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Web.xml :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 version="2.5">
  <display-name>Struts2Application</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
  <filter-name>Struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
  </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

The application running perfectly(`http://localhost:8080/Struts2Application/LoginClass.action`) when i remove the  `<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="jsp"/>` but i want to run in `http://localhost:8080/Struts2Application/LoginClass.jsp`. I have seen many links but nothing helped me.

Note :**I am using struts 2.3.20**

Someone tell me how to fix this?

Updated :

see my application structure here.

[image]

Comment: You have `Home.jsp` file not `home.jsp`. In your screenshots there is `html` extension not `jsp` so obviously it won't work with `LoginClass.jsp`.

Comment: In general you need redirect to action after hitting welcome page. Now you are trying to hit `.../Home.jsp` url which will be interpreted as action hit but you don't have action with `Home` name.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run this localhost:8080/App/LoginClass.jsp (i assume index.jsp is your default page), your web.xml file will look like as shown below

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

then include redirect link to App/LoginClass.jsp from index.jsp.

otherwise, follow this

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>App/LoginClass.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

above changes has to be done by  keeping

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true">
```

Am not sure whether this is relevant to your problem,

BTW, why do you want to use **struts.action.extension** ? whats the requirement?

**EDITED:**

can you try this...
keep your result pages inside a folder like this,

```
<result name="success">tempFolder/LoginSuccessPage.jsp</result> 
<result name="input">tempFolder/Home.jsp</result>
```

then use the

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="jsp"/>
```

and execute the program..results coming?

i think if we use **"struts.action.extension"**,, for the results present in **"root directory"** this page not found is occuring..
kindly test my above case and let me know whether it is working

**Edited 2:**
From your screen shot
You have 2 forward slash here-- Pages//Home.jsp **change it to** Pages/Home.jsp 

now try running

**Edited 3:**
try passing this from Home.jsp..append .action to existing action

```
<s:form action="LoginClass.action" method="post">
```

and execute.. sorry i couldn't try executing program here..i would've got a better idea if i execute

Comment: I think you didnt understand my question.see this "struts.action.extension to configure the URL suffix to for Struts2 application. Default suffix is .action but sometimes we might want to change it to .do or something else" so i am trying to change url loginclass.jsp instead of loginclass.action(default).

Comment: "i assume index.jsp is your default page" is wrong.Check my updated question.

Comment: i said "assume" because you didnot post your web.xml before, but web.xml is not required to analyze for this issue i believe

Comment: did you try giving  <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="do"/>     or <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="html"/>  and check whether it is working ??

Comment: even i tried value="html" but no use.I dont know why this is not working i am doing by tutorials http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/how-to-remove-the-action-suffix-extension-in-struts-2/ and  more

Comment: xxxggggggggggggggggggggg

Comment: this is my orginal url http://localhost:8080/Struts2Application/LoginClass i said that /App for example only.

Comment: i can understand your problem

Comment: can you try this...keep your result pages inside a folder like this,              <result name="success">/tempFolder/LoginSuccessPage.jsp</result>
   <result name="input">/tempFolder/Home.jsp</result> then use the <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="jsp"/> and execute the program..results coming?

Comment: i think if we use "struts.action.extension",, for the results present in "root directory: this page not found is occuring..kindly test my above case and let me know whether it is working

Comment: am eager to know the results,

Comment: Sorry it also didnt help me... check my updated question

Comment: try removing forward slash and run....<result name="success">Pages/LoginSuccessPage.jsp</result> 
<result name="input">Pages/Home.jsp</result>

Comment: and you have 2 forward slash here-- Pages//Home.jsp change it to Pages/Home.jsp

Comment: whats up dude!! is it running?

Comment: I did everything what u said above but no use Mr.Lyon

Comment: try passing this from Home.jsp..append .action to existing action                                                         <s:form action="LoginClass.action" method="post"> and execute.. sorry i couldn't try executing program here.. i would've got a better idea if i execute

Comment: wait for few mins i will be back

Comment: "Home.jsp..append .action to existing action" i tried this one too but no use again..

Comment: incase you didnt find a way, i will recreate this after 4 hours and update you

Comment: you got answers for it?